# Can I make a short trip to Northern Ireland?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am an Indian having UK's Tier 2 Visa. I have spent a month in Sheffield, UK. Now I want to visit Northern Ireland, Belfast.

Can I make a short trip there with Tier 2 Visa. Or I will have to apply for seperate Tourists Visa of Northern Ireland?

Comment: You used to be able to go on a 'Short trip', but I'm not sure if anyone is still flying them into Belfast ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_360 was common on the route)

Comment: @PeteKirkham: if they ever bring back internment, it will be for people who perpetrate puns like that...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Northern Ireland is part of the UK and for you visiting there as far as visas are concerned should be no different than visiting Manchester (UK).

Comment: @prashantzombade You just have to be careful that you don't leave Northern Ireland and enter the Republic of Ireland by mistake. The border is not always obviously marked and recognizable as an international border and you are not allowed to enter the Republic with a UK tier 2 visa.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57080/discussion-on-answer-by-pnuts-can-i-make-a-short-trip-to-northern-ireland).

Answer (score 0):

**`Yes, 100% Possible!!!`**

Personally i had a wonderful trip from England... I'm from India too had Tire 2 UK WP visa and no additional visa required (for including Scotland and Wales)

Traveled in Ryan Air from Stansed (London) to Belfast which was too budget friendly!!

**Bucket List:**

> Belfast: (Within city limit places)

1. Titanic museum
2. Belfast city hall
3. Ulster Museum
4. Albert Memorial clock
5. Big fish/ Beacon of Hope / Queens Bridge
6. SS Nomadic Ship
7. Belfast harbor marina (Walk) / Titanic quarter.
8. Victoria Square
9. Botanic Gardens
10. Yellow dot trail (Good for Shopping)

> Game Of Thrones locations: (Booked with McComb's via Tripadviser)

1. The Dark Hedges
2. Giant's Causeway
3. Carrick a reed rope bridge
4. Bravos canal
5. Storm's end cave

And Lots more.....